# C++ Linking - Own shared library type conflicts with other shared library

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, opencl, llvm

I have a problem with my custom shared library.
The shared library uses OpenCL to offload CPU intensive calculations to DSPs.
For testing I wrote a QT app which uses QCustomPlot to plot outputs of DSPs in realtime. 
When executing my test app (created with QTCreator) I get the following error:

```
test-libaudio-x15: /build/ti-llvm-3.3-DgVvHD/ti-llvm-3.3-3.3-git20150413/include/llvm/Support/CommandLine.h:674: void llvm::cl::parser<DataType>::addLiteralOption(const char*, const DT&, const char*) [with DT = llvm::ScheduleDAGInstrs* (*)(llvm::MachineSchedContext*); DataType = llvm::ScheduleDAGInstrs* (*)(llvm::MachineSchedContext*)]: Assertion »findOption(Name) == Values.size() && "Option already exists!"« failed.
```

My lib uses TI OpenCL which seems to have conflicting types with llvm OpenCL. When building the lib I link against TI-OpenCL. When building QT app I (indirectly) link against llvm OpenCL (from QT printsupport).
I already tried to use library as static as well, but the same problems occurs.

Thanks!

Comment: This does not look like a linking problem to me.

Comment: Ok, any other suggestion?

Comment: My OpenCL kernel code is compiled just in time. Maybe this causes the error? hmm